# Flutter: strokeWidth getting called on null in listview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a paint app where you can have multiple brushes now when add the brush to the list it does get added to list but when I try to show using `listview.builder` it shows `strokeWidth` called on `null`.

provider class,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:paint_app/models/brush.dart';

class BrushProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, Brush> _brush = {};
  Map<String, Brush> get brush => _brush;

  int get brushCount => _brush.length;

  void addBrush(double strokeWidth, Color color, String id) {
    if (_brush.containsKey(strokeWidth)) {
      _brush.update(
        id,
        (value) => Brush(color: color, id: id, strokeWidth: strokeWidth),
      );
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      _brush.putIfAbsent(
        id,
        () => Brush(
            strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
            id: DateTime.now().toString(),
            color: color),
      );
      notifyListeners();
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

place where I'm tring to show it,

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<Offset> _points = <Offset>[];
  AnimationController _controller;
  double value = 1;
  Color pickerColor = Color(0xff443a49);
  Color currentColor = Color(0xff443a49);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final brushes = Provider.of<BrushProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            Text(
              'Add Stroke width',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            SliderTheme(
              data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                activeTrackColor: Colors.red[700],
                inactiveTrackColor: Colors.red[100],
                trackShape: RoundedRectSliderTrackShape(),
                trackHeight: 4.0,
                thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 12.0),
                thumbColor: Colors.redAccent,
                overlayColor: Colors.red.withAlpha(32),
                overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 28.0),
                tickMarkShape: RoundSliderTickMarkShape(),
                activeTickMarkColor: Colors.red[700],
                inactiveTickMarkColor: Colors.red[100],
                valueIndicatorShape: PaddleSliderValueIndicatorShape(),
                valueIndicatorColor: Colors.redAccent,
                valueIndicatorTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              child: Slider(
                value: value,
                min: 1,
                max: 30,
                divisions: 30,
                label: '${value.round()}',
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      value = v;
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                brushes.addBrush(
                    value, currentColor, DateTime.now().toString()); //<-- adding to the list
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  primary: Colors.blueGrey),
            ),
            Divider(
              thickness: 2,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount:
                     brushes.brush.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (brushes.brush.length == null ) {
                    return Text('No Brushes');
                  }
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Text(
                        'Stroke Width: ${brushes.brush[index].strokeWidth}'), // <-- here trying to show
                    color: brushes.brush[index].color,
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
body:(rest of the code...)
```

model class,

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Brush{
  final Color color;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final String id;

  Brush({this.strokeWidth,this.color,this.id});
}
```

can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are working with a map `brushes.brush`, that depends on `'key':'value'` pairs, but you are treating it like a list, which depends on `[index]`.

You can convert your map to a List, then working with it in `ListView.builder`.

Try this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final brushes = Provider.of<BrushProvider>(context, listen:true);
List<Brush> brushList = brushes.brush.entries.map((entry) =>  entry.value).toList();
```

and in your `ListView.builder`, change it to this:

```
      ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount:
                 brushList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (brushList.isEmpty ) {
                return Text('No Brushes');
              }
              return Container(
                height: 50,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Text(
                    'Stroke Width: ${brushList[index].strokeWidth}'), // <-- should work now
                color: brushList[index].color,
              );
            }),
```

Comment: ok thank you so much that works like charm but is there any better way to do this or I'm doing is fine?

Comment: You're most welcome, I'm not an expert but I think you are doing just fine. I was able to understand what your code and state management is supposed to be doing, because you are using names that make sense. Perhaps you were missing a simple concept, but things look fine. I changed your provider to `listen: true` , so your list can stay updated if anything is removed or added. Keep going!